# How to access a variable from another controller in a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

My question is kind of a generalized one and I don't really know how to provide code for it. But, I was wondering if I could pass variables into a new page containing a form. Basically, the gist of my problem is I have a carpools table, a trips table, and a users table. The relevant models are shown below

users

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #associations
  has_many :users_trips
  has_many :carpools
  has_many :trips, :through => :users_trips
end
```

trips

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  #including the wysiwyg editor
  include Bootsy::Container

  #associations
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :carpools
  has_many :users_trips
  has_many :users, :through => :users_trips

  #make sure trips get ordered from newest to oldest
  default_scope -> { order(start_date: :desc) }

  #validations
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :description, presence: true
  validates :start_date, presence: true
  validates :end_date, presence: true
end
```

and carpools

```
class Carpool < ActiveRecord::Base
  #associations
  belongs_to :trip
  belongs_to :user

  #validations
  validates :trip_id, presence: true
  validates :make, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :model, presence: true
  validates :leave_time, presence: true
  validates :seats, presence: true
  validates :year, presence: true
end
```

Also, if it helps, i have a many-to-many relationship table called users_trips. I am currently trying to have a user have the ability to sign his/her car up for a trip (hence a carpools table). But when I began to think about the form for the carpool, I realized I was going to have a problem passing the trip_id to the carpool. Assume each of the respective controllers for users/trips are correct. The controller for the carpools has not been made yet.

Also, if it helps, I currently have the idea of, on the trip page, there will be a button that allows the user to sign his/her car up for the trip. That button will lead to the form where the user can fill in the respective fields for their car.

Comment: You can setup any variables you want in your controller, and they will be accessible to your view. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I guess the title of my question is misleading, but idk what to title this question as. I realize that i can setup any variables I want in my controller, but the problem I am having is that, while I can get the id of the current user any time i want (through cookies), I cannot get the id of a specific trip at any time I want unless I was operating with that controller. So, I came to here to try to find out how to pass the id of a specific trip onto the form of a carpool for that trip.

Comment: should I just create an application-wide variable that updates with the current trip id every-time a user looks at a trip?

Comment: Like `session[:trip_id] = @current_trip_id`? Sure.

Comment: wait, how do sessions work, if I save a trip_id onto the session, how do i keep it persistent, and if the user logs out, do i have to delete it?

Comment: @cmeks - See this docs it has great example for the functionality u want. [http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=2.3#top